# Unicode console output with wxwidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to use wxwidgets 3.0.3 with mingw-w64 on Windows.

wxPrintf is patched like https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/06458cb89fb8449f377b0b782404b9a9cbe3ae2d#diff-9cf4eef4822377649a928c11237e38f6

Source code is saved in UTF-8

I init wxLocale like:

```
wxLocale m_locale;
m_locale.Init(wxLANGUAGE_RUSSIAN , wxLOCALE_DONT_LOAD_DEFAULT  )
```

The console output has 8 bit encoding (CP866), that I can check with `GetConsoleOutputCP()` and `GetConsoleCP()`. So I have correct output for Latin and Russian characters, but not for Greek (Lucida Console font is used):

```
wxString s = L"Latin, Русский, \u03BE ρπξ\n\n";
```

or

```
wxString s = wxString::FromUTF8("Latin, Русский, \u03BE ρπξ\n\n");

wxPrintf(s.utf8_str()); // not correct output for Greek
```

If I force console output to be UTF-8:

```
SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
```

the `wxPrintf` doesn't work correct.
(I can have correct output once using `std::cout << s.utf8_str().data()`. Some memory leak?)

Using `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_WINUNICODE);` doesn't change the console encoding (remain cp866).

Is there way to use standard wxWidgets means (wxPrintf and Stream classes provided by wxWidgets library) to use Unicode console output?

Comment: does the font have an appropriate glyps?

Comment: @Igor Yes, It does